# cx-Oracle cannot locate Oracle client library

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

VScode gave me the following error when trying to run my code. It was working a few days ago. The only thing that changed is that Windows updated automatically.

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "Access is denied"
```

I checked with `pip freeze` and I do have cx-Oracle in my environment:

```
astroid==2.4.1
click==7.1.2
colorama==0.4.3
cx-Oracle==8.0.0
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.3
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
pylint==2.5.2
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18
toml==0.10.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wrapt==1.12.1
```

I uninstalled cx-Oracle and installed it again, but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the real solution as I got this working just by guessing. I installed the latest oracle client, added it to the environment variable and checked. It did not work. then I restarted the Machine and it worked.